# Create simple loyalty program, reward point

Tags: magento2

I can't find a tutorial on how to create a loyalty program,i want add reward point on admin panel. Can anyone recommend a free tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension for the rewards program :

https://marketplace.magento.com/yotpo-magento2-module-yotpo-loyalty.html

Comment: This is great, but I'm looking for a tutorial with instructions

Comment: You can just install this extension and their team will guide you regarding this